# How to enable \KOMAoptions{twoside = false} using geometry package

Tags: koma-script, geometry

I'm new to Latex and just started using it for writing my thesis.

I got a nice working template from my professor but the issue is that he was using `\KOMAoptions{twoside = false}` in the middle of the document what occurred in a typearea changed warning. I was continuing researching for options and google came up with the geometry package.

So I tried the following:

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
\newgeometry{ 
  \KOMAoptions{twoside = false}  }

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\Huge{\textbf{Titel}}\\[3ex]
\Large{\textbf{Untertitel der Arbeit}}\\[4ex]

\Large{\textbf{Bachelor/Master-Thesis}}\\[1ex]
\Large{Fakultät Elektrotechnik und Informatik}\\[4ex]

\includegraphics[width=8cm]{images/hswgt.pdf}\\[4ex]

\Large{zur Erlangung des akademischen Grades}\\[1ex]
\Large{\textbf{Bachelor/Master of Science}}\\[3ex]

\normalsize
\begin{tabular}{rl}\\
  vorgelegt von: & \quad Max Mustermann\\[1.2ex]
  Studiengang: & \quad Wirtschaftsinformatik\\[1.2ex]
  Matrikelnummer: & \quad 12345\\[1.2ex]
  Erstgutachter: & \quad Prof. Dr. Max Mustermann\\[1.2ex]
  Zweitgutachter: & \quad Prof. Dr. Max Mustermann\\[3ex]
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\advance\oddsidemargin by 0.5cm % Text verschieben
\advance\evensidemargin by -0.5cm % Text verschieben 
\restoregeometry
```

Unfortunately, this brought up two new errors. Please see the attached screenshot of the errors.

Can anyone help me fix that? [image]

This is my root document (sorry probably not the right name but I guess thats what you guys want to see)

```
\documentclass[12pt,pdftex,a4paper,parskip=half]{scrbook} % Haupteinstellungen
\usepackage{ngerman} % Deutsche Sprachdatei
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Deutsche Umlaute
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Schriftart
\usepackage{graphicx} % Grafiken einbinden
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} % Mathematische Formeln
\usepackage{mathtools} % Mathematische Formeln
\usepackage{setspace} % Zeilenabstand
\usepackage{lmodern} % Vektorschriftart Modern
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % Trennung URLs
\usepackage{acronym} % Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage{listings} % Code
\usepackage{geometry} % Ermöglicht lokale Layout-Änderungen
\usepackage{booktabs} % Schöne Tabellen
\usepackage{tabularx} % Tabellen
\usepackage{scrhack} % Deprecated Methoden unterdrücken
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} % Gebraucht für BibStyle\documentclass[10pt]{•}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first/first-last} % Erst Nachname im Literaturverzeichnis

\addbibresource{bib/Literatur.bib}

\newenvironment{itemize*}%
  {\begin{itemize}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{2pt}}%
  {\end{itemize}}

\newenvironment{enumerate*}%
  {\begin{enumerate}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{2pt}}%
  {\end{enumerate}}

\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{ %Einrueckung der Fussnoten wird korrigiert
    \textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark\ }
}

\lstset{%
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,     % Sprache des Quellcodes ist TeX
    stepnumber=1,            % Jede Zeile nummerieren.
    numbersep=5pt,           % 5pt Abstand zum Quellcode
    numberstyle=\tiny,       % Zeichengrösse 'tiny' für die Nummern.
    breaklines=true,         % Zeilen umbrechen wenn notwendig.
    breakautoindent=true,    % Nach dem Zeilenumbruch Zeile einrücken.
    postbreak=\space,        % Bei Leerzeichen umbrechen.
    tabsize=2,               % Tabulatorgrösse 2
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize, % Nichtproportionale Schrift, klein für den Quellcode
    showspaces=false,        % Leerzeichen nicht anzeigen.
    showstringspaces=false,  % Leerzeichen auch in Strings ('') nicht anzeigen.
    extendedchars=true      % Alle Zeichen vom Latin1 Zeichensatz anzeigen.
} % Hintergrundfarbe des Quellcodes setzen.

%Trennung von Wörtern
\hyphenation{Such-er-geb-nis-se}
\hyphenation{Such-er-geb-nis-sen}

\pdfminorversion 6 % PDF-Version 1.6
\onehalfspacing % Zeilenabstand 1,5

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain} % Keine Kopfzeilen
\input{Titelseite} % Titelseite
\input{Erklaerung} % Eidesstattliche Erklärung
\input{Vorwort} % Vorwort
\input{Abstract} % Abstract\tableofcontents % Inhaltsverzeichnis
\clearpage % Neue Seite
\input{Abkuerzungsverzeichnis} % Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\cleardoublepage % Neue Seite
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis} % Überschrift Abbildungsverzeichnis
\listoffigures % Abbildungsverzeichnis
\cleardoublepage % Neue Seite
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tabellenverzeichnis} % Überschrift Tabellenverzeichnis
\listoftables % Tabellenverzeichnis
\tableofcontents % Inhaltsverzeichnis
\input{Kapitel1}
\input{Kapitel2}
\input{Kapitel3}
\input{Kapitel4}
\input{Kapitel5}
\cleardoublepage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]

\appendix
\input{Anhang}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The warning about using `\typearea` inside the document is only because `typearea` needs to use internals of the LaTeX kernel so that there is no guaranty that it works and that it works for all possible backend drivers. But currently it does work for decades. So I would recommend to ignore the warning. `\newgeometry` allows only options of `geometry`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a *complete* document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and that produces the errors that you show above.

Comment: Thank you for the first feedback guys - If nobody has a different approach I'll just have to live with the warning

Comment: The problem is not the warnings but the errors that you show above. They are caused by the line `\newgeometry{\KOMAoptions{twoside = false}}`. You just can't do that. `\newgeometry` expects keywords regarding the margins etc, but not the macro `\KOMAoptions` which has to be used outside of `\newgeometry`.

Comment: You must not enclose `\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}` into `\newgeometry`. I'm not sure what approach should be made (or what you do mean by that). Did your professor include the `geometry`-package?

Comment: @JohnKormylo: No, they won't fight. There is at least a KOMA-Script option `usegeometry`. With this you can use `typearea` even to increase the featureset of `geometry`.

Comment: @Skillmon no he didn't. He just did it without the geometry stuff and told me the warning did not occur before

Comment: Just to clarify. I'm not searching for a solution with geometry just a working solution with no warnings that allows me to use the >\KOMAoptions{twoside = false}  in the middle of my document

Comment: Use `\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}` (without `\newgeometry`) and ignore the warning. I think the warning is an anachronism from the very beginning of KOMA-Script, when LaTeX2e was new and the author wasn't sure, that using and changing internal lengths of LaTeX2e is save.

Comment: Alright @Schweinebacke I'll just ignore it - I mean I can't see any disadvantages so it should be fine - Thanks to everybody

Answer (score 1):

Since [KOMA-Script release 3.23](http://www.komascript.de/release3.23) changing page size or size of typing area or option `twoside` or another parameter that results in recalculation of typing area and margins does not longer result in a warning message but only in an info (shown only in the `log` file), e.g.:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext[3]

\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}
\Blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

does not longer show a warning on the terminal:

> ```
> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty)) (./test.aux)
> [1] [2] (./test.aux) )
> Output written on test.pdf (2 pages).
> ```

but only:

> ```
> [1
>
> ]
> Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
> (typearea)             DIV  = 10
> (typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
> (typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
> (typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
> (typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
> (typearea)              \evensidemargin = 17.3562pt
> (typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 17.3562pt
> (typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
> (typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
> (typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
> (typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
> (typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
> (typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
> (typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
> (typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
> (typearea)              on input line 7.
> Package typearea Info: Using dirty hack to recalculate internal output
> (typearea)             dimensions of LaTeX on input line 7.
>  [2
>
> ]
> ```

in the `log` file.

So the problem with the unwanted warning should be solved.